# Trouble using get_post

Tags: get-posts

For Microkids [related post plugin](http://www.microkid.net/wordpress/related-posts/)
He said

> "Using the get_post() function you could get any data you need from
>   the related posts."

and he posted this snippet of code.

```
$related_posts = MRP_get_related_posts( $post_id );
```

I'm not exactly sure how to use the get_post feature for this situation. I would like to display the titles and thumbnail for each post in that array. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possibly:

```
$related_posts = MRP_get_related_posts( $post->ID );   
    if( $related_posts ) foreach( $related_posts as $key=>$value ) { 
        //only holds the following information:
        //echo $key; //the related_post_id  
        //echo $value;  //the related post title
        echo get_the_title($key);     
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($key);   
    }
```

(edited after downloading and testing the plugin)

Comment: Hey Michael, it's throwing a "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error.

Comment: possibly my mistake, as I don't know for sure what 'MRP_get_related_posts()' returns - you can test that with `var_dump(MRP_get_related_posts( $post_id ))` - or possibly because there are no related posts at the moment (reply corrected for that case).

Comment: I tried the var_dump and I got 'null' - there is a explanation on this page about what the MRP_get_related_posts function can do. It's under API Functions - http://www.microkid.net/wordpress/related-posts/#API

Comment: what is the value of `$post_id` ? if this is not defined, try to use `$post->ID` instead.

Comment: answer edited after testing the plugin. if it works with `$post->ID` might depend on the location where you use the code.

Comment: amazing! Thank you so much. The only remaining part is wrapping the permalink around both. I used this in my sidebar for recent posts and would love to do the same for this.  
 `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'sideThumb', array('class' => 'alignleftthumb')); ?> </a>`

Comment: `<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'sideThumb', array('class' => 'alignleftthumb')); ?> </a>`

Comment: The working code prints out all of the related entries and when I put in the code that wraps the permalink around the title and image it only displays the first entry - not the rest. I'm not sure how to set up a loop so everything is combined. Thanks again.

Comment: @Chad - try: `echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($key) . '">' . get_the_title($key) . get_the_post_thumbnail($key) . '</a>';`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `get_posts`, I'd recommend using [`get_the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) and [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) to get the data that you need. You can use them like:

```
echo get_the_title($post_id);
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail');
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the info, the code outputted the title and thumbnail of the post that I am currently viewing not the posts from MRP_get_related_posts. My query might be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $post_type = ( $instance['post_type'] == 'all' ) ? null : $instance['post_type'];
    $related_posts = MRP_get_related_posts( $post->ID, 0, 0, $post_type );
    if( $related_posts ) {
        echo "<div id='boxes'><div class='container'> \n";
        foreach( $related_posts as $related_post_id => $related_post_title  ) {
            if ( '' != get_the_post_thumbnail($related_post_id) ) {
                $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($related_post_id);
                $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, true);
                $theImage = $thumb_url[0];
            } else {
                $theImage = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/img/trama-01.gif';
            }
            echo '<div class="box simple" style="background-image:url('.$theImage.')"><div class="box-content"><div class="wrapper"><div class="cover">';
            echo "<div class='titulo'><a href=\"".get_permalink( $related_post_id )."\"><h3>".get_post_meta($post->ID,'wpcf-tagline',TRUE)."</h3><h1>".$related_post_title."</h1></a></div>";
            echo "</div></div></div></div>\n";
        }
        echo "</div></div>";
    }
?>
```

The markup I needed to achieve was:

```
<div class='box simple' style="background-image:url(../img/banner-01.jpg)">
    <div class='box-content'>
        <div class='wrapper'>
        <div class='cover'>
            <div class="titulo">
                        <a href="#">
                            <h3>WP Types Tagline custom field here</h3>
                            <h1>Title here</h1>
                        </a>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps someone,

Best.

Comment: Don't just post code and says it worked. Always add an explanation to why it worked or to why your code should work

Comment: Ok, it worked because I had that particular markup -that I shared-, and I managed to get the display code out of the 'microkids-related-posts-widget.php' file and rearranged it to display recent posts in my single.php -where I needed them to appear- with the image, title and custom fields (I used WP Types plugin for custom fields BTW).